# Is there a better way to get a copy of DataRowView?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a collection of `DataRowView` bound to a `DataGrid`. For some functionalities, I need to get copies of some `DataRowView`s. I'm using the following method to get it.

```
public static DataRowView GetCopyOfRowView(DataRowView rowView)
{
   DataTable table = rowView.DataView.ToTable();
   DataRow copyRow = table.NewRow();
   copyRow.ItemArray = rowView.Row.ItemArray;
   table.Rows.InsertAt(copyRow, table.Rows.Count);
   return table.DefaultView[table.Rows.Count - 1];
}
```

But this method could prove very costly for more than 1000 rows. Is there a better way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

DataTable has a Copy method that copies the schema and data. Could you use that? You said you need to copy more than 1000 rows...

Comment: That would just give me a copy of the DataTable.  I have Observable Collection of DataRowView objects. I need to get a copy of say 1000  `DataRowView` objects from that collection.

Comment: Yea I was thinking you could get the rows you need from the copied table. Do you need shallow copies or deep copies?